# React - Communicate between Parent and Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a picture of what I'm trying to implement.
I need the parent's handleChange function(optimised) to help all its children update their state and ids.

```
  <Parent>

       constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
           child1State: null, child2State: null, child3State: null
          }
        }

        handleChange(){
          /* Add code to update the id of the changed element
           If bound attribute is present, numerize the e.target.value then update the id of the changed element]
           Previously this was with the child and handled using    
           this.setState({value: e.target.value});
           this.context.tree.select('app').set(this.props.id, (e.target.value));
           if (this.props.bound) this.context.tree.select('app').set(this.props.bound, Number(e.target.value));
           now this.props.id is undefined when I moved handleChange to the parent
          */

          this.setState({child1State: e.target.value});
        }

        onreset(){
          // here I would basically want the child1State and Child2State(select) to reset its value(would want something more optimised)
          this.setState({child1State: null});
        }

       <Child id="child1" value="this.props.child1State" bound="SelectedChild1" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></Child>
       <Child id="child2" value="this.props.child1State" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this}></Child>
       <Child id="child3" value="this.props.child1State" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></Child>
       <Button>Reset Child1 and Child2<Button>
    <Parent>
```

This is the child which is basically a select dropdown.Now when Child1 is updated Child2 should have values corresponding to Child1.Suppose if Child1 is City then Child2 should display a list of cities.If Child1 is countries the corresponding country list should be displayed in child2.and on clicking reset - These select boxes should display the default disabled null value!Child3 is another dropdown which on onChange should change its state, bind value to its id- do nothing else.

```
    <Child>
      <select id={this.props.id} value={that.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange}>
       if(that.props.placeholder) return <option disabled selected>{that.props.placeholder}</option>
       {
         this.props.options.map(function(data, i) {
           return <option value={data.value} key={i}>{data.name{that.props.displayValue ? '(' + data.value + ')' : ''}</option>
        })
       }
      </select>
    </Child>
```

Comment: So child1(countries) when updated should update child2 ( list of countries) then why not keep child2 as child of child1 , that way you would be able to pass the country name from child1 as prop to child2 and then change child2 accordingly. This would make your code lean.

Can you provide more explanation for child3, its not much clear now.

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja I have SelectField as my Child class and Filters as my Parent Class.Filter basically has a set of SelectFields.Child3 is a select field with options.Child2 is dependent on Child1.I thought of making SelectField a child class ? I have usually seen buttons / input as individual components.I haven't seen a button component inside another button component -Is that valid?

Comment: yeah that should work, one component should take care of a single task not mutiple. So I would suggest you create a separate component if you feel child2 is child of child1.